# Strange results quering WMI information

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wmic

I write simple batch file to fast check network interface status:

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%q in ('wmic path win32_networkadapter where "netconnectionid like '%%ovpn_wintun%%'" get netconnectionstatus /format:list ^| find ^/i ^"NetConnectionStatus^"') do (
echo q variable is: %%q
IF %%q LEQ 2 echo 1. q less or equal %%q
IF %%q EQU 2 echo 2. q equal %%q
IF %%q GEQ 2 echo 3. q greater or equal %%q
IF %%q LEQ 3 echo 4. q less or equal %%q
IF %%q EQU 3 echo 5. q equal %%q
IF %%q GEQ 3 echo 6. q greater or equal %%q
)
endlocal
pause
```

And receive unexpected results:

[image: Execution results]

Compare variables as string have no result.

Can someone explain me, please, what is it and it is fixable in batch script?

Comment: Change ```find ^/i ^"NetConnectionStatus^"``` to ```find /i "NetConnectionStatus"```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by the fact that `wmic` output is not only Unicode, but also has an output with line terminals like <kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>LF</kbd>.

You could observe this by outputting `%%q` to a file and examining the file with `editplus` or a similar real text editor.

Here's a quick-fix (noting that I've modified the `wmic` command to suit my system)

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%q in ('wmic path win32_networkadapter where "netconnectionid like '%%ethernet%%'" get netconnectionstatus /format:list ^| find ^/i ^"NetConnectionStatus^"') do (
 echo q variable is: %%q
 SET /a QQ=%%q
 SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
 IF !qq! LEQ 2 echo 1. q less or equal %%q
 IF !qq! EQU 2 echo 2. q equal %%q
 IF !qq! GEQ 2 echo 3. q greater or equal %%q
 IF !qq! LEQ 3 echo 4. q less or equal %%q
 IF !qq! EQU 3 echo 5. q equal %%q
 IF !qq! GEQ 3 echo 6. q greater or equal %%q
 endlocal
)

SET Q
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for answer it work. I see line ending set to CR in my case, but can i force set output with CR/LF instead CR?

Comment: Unfortunately no, as far as I am aware